# How to work with control bones when armature follows a path

Tags: rigging

I have a spaceship model I'm working on in blender 2.8. The model is rigged with control bones to control the animation of landing struts/wings etc. I've made the rig and the control bones do what I want it do do.

However I want the spaceship to follow a course through an environment which I have laid out with a path. Path animation works fine and the spaceship moves.

The problem I am having is that when the rigged spaceship follows the path the animations are triggering when I don't want to because the control bones are moving along with the rest of the armature - for example landing legs are controlled by moving the control bones along the X-axis, but are triggered when the entire armature moves along the X-axis following the path.

Comment: Have you give the Follow Path constraint to the armature or to one of its bone?

Comment: I gave it to the entire armature, but seen a comment about a root bone which I haven't sett up which is probably the problem

Comment: yes that what I was suggesting but it's not clear how your armature is made, maybe share the armature only here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/2caaeac344724ac987cdf5ebd4705015 I've shared the armature now. Though I did try parenting my control bones to a root bone but movement still triggered the animations (Version I've posted is before I did some parenting.

Comment: wow seems complicated, what are your Action constraints for? Maybe switch from Target > World Space to Local Space?

Comment: The action constraints are used to open the 'wings' on the back and move the 'legs' or landing gear up and down. When I tried changing the target from world to local it messed the orientation of my bones

Comment: yes but as it is set to world, I guess as soon as you'll move your armature it will mess your bones as they will be constrained by a world location, it's not a question of follow path

Comment: Changing the target from world to local caused the constraint to stop working entirely

Comment: I think you'll need to change the settings otherwise the controller transformations that will be taken into account are the one in World Space. This is not what you want as the bones that have the constraints will begin to move when the entire armature will move in the Global Space. You need to switch to Local Space and set the target bone Range Min and Max value, and they will depend on the XYZ axis of the bone itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to switch the *Action* constraints from *Global* to *Local*, otherwise, any movement of the armature will move the controller bone in the global space and it will trigger the action for the controlled bone.

To do so, switch the *Target* to *Local Space*. *Range Min* and *Max* will determine the range of the bone that will be taken into account, relative to its default position in *Edit* mode and in grid unit:

[image]

Now when I move the controller bone 3 units on its Y axis (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>) here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much moonboots. I'll give this a try and see how I get on!

Comment: by the way, maybe you should do all that with the NLA? unless you have good reason to use a constraint but NLA seems easier to manage

Comment: "when the axis is similar"? What do you mean? As you can see in my screenshots it works fine, you need to consider the bone own axis, not the armature axis